# Spring boot handler interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, interceptor

I have a spring boot application which contains interceptor. The issue is the request is directly hitting the api instead of the interceptor.

This is my configuration class which register the interceptor.

```
@Configuration

public class AuthenticationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizeInterceptor authorizeInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(authorizeInterceptor);
    }
}

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AuthorizeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3)
            throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("POST HANDLE REQUEST------------");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object arg2) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("PREHANDLE REQUEST-------------");     
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have SpringWebMvc enabled? if no, try to add @ EnableWebMvc after @ Configuration in your AuthenticationConfiguration class

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using? Can you share your main application class as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have created totally same project in your case and interceptor works fine. may be you need to check your Logger configuration or `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` in your application properties

Did you try System.out.println instead of LOGGER.debug ?

Comment: I switched to OncePerRequestFilter as per the req. And registered the beans in configuration. Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 @Autowired
    private AuthorizeInterceptor authorizeInterceptor;
```

Add

```
 @Autowired
    HandlerInterceptor interceptor;
```